# REST MVC - Can't Pass # character on parameter type String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

I'm new on REST and I created my First REST MVC API.
I have one method call `recibir` which receives one string parameter `"(string eventos)"` and when I want to pass the string `"2013-10-1117:59:59;10;0#2013-10-1118:00:00;12;0#"` on server side (Action `recibir` on my Apicontroller) only receive in eventos parameter the first part of the string passed `"2013-10-1117:59:59;10;0"` until `#`.

I don't know if I can pass the `#` but with other characters I haven't got any problems.

An example of a call to my rest is:

`http://localhost:56010/commentApi/recibir?eventos=2013-10-1117:59:59;10;0#2013-10-1118:00:00;12;0#`

And in my server side I recieve from parameter eventos `"2013-10-1117:59:59;10;0"`

Thanks and excuse me because my english is not the best. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to encode the # symbol, since it is a reserved symbol in URLs.

So when creating those links, you should use something like [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).